# dropzone chunk uploading: what callbacks should I use to call ajax and process files/chunks?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm trying to correctly implement chunk uploading with dropzone js and php. My main concern is: where should I do my ajax call(s)? Normally (no chunks), you'll just specify the URL param. But with chunks, this is not enough, I guess, because there will be only 1 ajax call, but ideally, the chunks will be several, and we have to wait for all before reassembling the whole file with php. So, in your experience, what's the correct place to do the ajax call or calls? (Is maybe a way to do only one call?). Here's a simplyfied extract of my current code:

```
window['dropzone' + panel_index] = new Dropzone(
  selector,
  {
    url: ajax_url + '?action=uploadfile'
    ,addRemoveLinks: true
    ,maxFiles: 5
    ,maxFilesize: maxfilesize
    ,uploadMultiple:false
    ,parallelUploads: 1
    ,chunking:true
    ,forceChunking:true
    ,chunkSize:10485760 // 10Mb
    ,retryChunks: true   // retry chunks on failure
    ,retryChunksLimit: 3
    ,chunksUploaded:function(file, done){
      // called only once, when chunks are finished > do something ajax > php to reassemble the file?
      done();
    }
    ,params: function(file, xhr, chunk){

      // called once per every chunk > do something ajax > php?

      if(chunk){
        $.extend(true, p, {
          dzuuid: chunk.file.upload.uuid,
          dzchunkindex: chunk.index,
          dztotalfilesize: chunk.file.size,
          dzchunksize: this.options.chunkSize,
          dztotalchunkcount: chunk.file.upload.totalChunkCount,
          dzchunkbyteoffset: chunk.index * this.options.chunkSize
        });
      }

      return p;
    }// params


    ,init: function(){
      this.on('success', function(newfile){
        // called after chunksUploaded > do something ajax > php?
      });// onsuccess

      this.on('uploadprogress', function(file, progress, bytesent){
        // called continuously
      })
    }// dropzone init option
  }// dropzone options
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, the only callback needed for serve-side chunk processing is the function passed to `params`. Something like this (extract from my code):

```
,params: function(files, xhr, chunk){

  var p = { // $_POST
    app_type: 'configurator'
    ,app_code: manager.code
    ,file_types: filetypes
    ,max_filesize: maxfilesize
    ,upf: upf
  }

  if(chunk){
    $.extend(true, p, {
      dzuuid: chunk.file.upload.uuid,
      dzchunkindex: chunk.index,
      dztotalfilesize: chunk.file.size,
      dzchunksize: this.options.chunkSize,
      dztotalchunkcount: chunk.file.upload.totalChunkCount,
      dzchunkbyteoffset: chunk.index * this.options.chunkSize
    });
  }

  return p;
}// params
```

The called url is just the general dropzone's url param. It's called once per every chunk.

In php, you can use $_POST['dzchunkindex'] to save chunks with modified name, for ex.

```
// do all the sanitisation tasks, then:
$target_chunk = $this->target_path . DS . $filename . $chunk_index;
// and then do the file saving tasks
```

After all the chunks are processed, you'll have as much files as the chunks on your server. Then, on the same function, check if the chunk index is like `dztotalchunkcount - 1` (in other worlds, if the current chunk is the last one) and in that case, also unite all the chunks in one file. Example:

```
if($chunk_index == $total_chunks - 1){
  $final = fopen($target_file, 'wb');   // Open for write and start from beginning of file
  for ($i = 0; $i < $total_chunks; $i++) {
    $file = fopen($target_file.$i, 'rb');
    while($buff = fread($file, 4096)){ fwrite($final, $buff); }
    fclose($file);
    unlink($target_file.$i);
  }
  fclose($final);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it inside of the `chunksUploaded` option. After Dropzone uploads all of the chunks for me, I perform another ajax call inside of `chunksUploaded` to a separate PHP script from my uploader that concatenates all of the uploaded files.

**So, each chunk upload calls the same Dropzone url that uploads the chunk in PHP:**

```php
<?php

/* ========================================
  VARIABLES
======================================== */

// chunk variables
$fileId = $_POST['dzuuid'];
$chunkIndex = $_POST['dzchunkindex'] + 1;
$chunkTotal = $_POST['dztotalchunkcount'];

// file path variables
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . "{$ds}uploads{$ds}";
$fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$fileSize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$filename = "{$fileId}-{$chunkIndex}.{$fileType}";
$targetFile = $targetPath . $filename;

/* ========================================
  DEPENDENCY FUNCTIONS
======================================== */

$returnResponse = function ($info = null, $filelink = null, $status = "error") {
  die (json_encode( array(
    "status" => $status,
    "info" => $info,
    "file_link" => $filelink
  )));
};

/* ========================================
  VALIDATION CHECKS
======================================== */

// I deleted a bunch of validation that goes here to keep the code short

/* ========================================
  CHUNK UPLOAD
======================================== */

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFile);

// Be sure that the file has been uploaded
if ( !file_exists($targetFile) ) $returnResponse("An error occurred and we couldn't upload the requested file.");
chmod($targetFile, 0777) or $returnResponse("Could not reset permissions on uploaded chunk.");

$returnResponse(null, null, "success");
```

**Then, chunksUploaded performs another ajax call to a concatenation php script (notice how I use the drop zone upload ID as a serial to identify which file chunks belong together):**

```php
<?php

// get variables
$fileId = $_GET['dzuuid'];
$chunkTotal = $_GET['dztotalchunkcount'];

// file path variables
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . "{$ds}uploads{$ds}";
//$fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_GET['fileName'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$fileType = $_GET['fileName'];

/* ========================================
  DEPENDENCY FUNCTIONS
======================================== */

$returnResponse = function ($info = null, $filelink = null, $status = "error") {
  die (json_encode( array(
    "status" => $status,
    "info" => $info,
    "file_link" => $filelink
  )));
};

/* ========================================
  CONCATENATE UPLOADED FILES
======================================== */

// loop through temp files and grab the content
for ($i = 1; $i <= $chunkTotal; $i++) {

  // target temp file
  $temp_file_path = realpath("{$targetPath}{$fileId}-{$i}.{$fileType}") or $returnResponse("Your chunk was lost mid-upload.");

  // copy chunk
  $chunk = file_get_contents($temp_file_path);
  if ( empty($chunk) ) $returnResponse("Chunks are uploading as empty strings.");

  // add chunk to main file
  file_put_contents("{$targetPath}{$fileId}.{$fileType}", $chunk, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

  // delete chunk
  unlink($temp_file_path);
  if ( file_exists($temp_file_path) ) $returnResponse("Your temp files could not be deleted.");

}

// and by the time you get here you should have your concatenated file in the "uploads" folder to do with what you want
```